# Apps Script | Can't .setValue() from a .getValue() cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, setvalue

```
libroBBDD.getRange(z + 1, partidosjugados)
  .setValue(10 += bbddpartidas.getRange(2 + j, tiempojugado).getValue())
```

With this code, I'm getting this error when I'm trying to setValue to a cell with the info I'm getting from another cell... No idea what I could do

```
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to concatenate the `10` with the `.getValue()` or trying to sum it up?

If the cell value is numeric with just `+` they will be summed up. If you would like to concatenate I would recommend using `"10"+ bbddpartidas.getRange(2 + j, tiempojugado).getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "+=". I just had to remove the "+"